# Storing a non-String data in Yesod Session?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I want know if it is possible to Store a non-String Data on a session?
e.g: is a  `List`.

If not what would be the great suggestion in this. the purpose of this is i have a planning using the [`Background Worker`](http://jdabbs.com/resquing-yesod/) to do some work and store it in a list.

hope you help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize the data to Text somehow. One option is via JSON using the aeson library.

Comment: thank you so you mean i can store JSON on a session? what bout in Cache is it also possible?